# Камера переворачивается назад во время навигации по сцене в Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Камера беспорядочно переворачивается во время навигации в редакторе по сцене (когда зажимаешь правую кнопку мыши и летаешь по WASD).

Вот, если лечу прямо в этом режиме, все хорошо, а если я начинаю двигать камеру мышкой, то оно начинает переворачиваться. Как это исправить?

[Видео пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8utAtC6FSKU)

Версия Unity 2021.1.11f1 Personal

Comment: Будет хорошо если вы приложите видео

Comment: @МаксимФисман сделал